# Collect statistic of Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite to cache SQL query result with native persistence enabled, so part of query result will be stored in disk.

When I fetch query result from cache, is there a way I can get statistic about how much data is loaded from memory and how much from disk for this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only relevant metric I know is `org.apache.ignite.DataRegionMetrics#getEvictionRate`, which lets you understand how often you are hitting disk, but it is not per-query granular.

Comment: @almar  DataRegionMetrics is deprecated, using GirdMetircManager instead, there are 2 registries:sys and pme, I didn't find this metirc in them and I didn't find the doc of GirdMetircManager either, do you have any hint for it?

Comment: I think you may use DataRegionMetrics for now. I'm not expert on GirdMetircManager metrics.